# inlining issue on solaris with developerstudio 12.6

Tags: c++, solaris

Consider the below code which shows the problem.

test.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func2(int x);

// inline the func1. 
inline int func1(int y)
{
     {
      return func2(y);
     }
  return 1;
}

int func2(int x)
{
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  if (func1(99))
      printf("This should never print\n");
  return 0;
}
```

/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -o test -m64 -xarch=sparc -O -xmaxopt +w2 -std=c++11 test.C

This prints the "This should never print" on my system.